# How to avoid "object not found" error with geom_abline?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot lines from a data frame with columns indicating the slope and intercept, but keep on getting an "object not found" error. Here is a reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(intercept = 1,
             slope = 0.5)

df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_abline(slope = slope, intercept = intercept)
#> Error in geom_abline(slope = slope, intercept = intercept): object 'slope' not found
```

I recognize that I must be missing something fairly rudimentary about the operation of `geom_abline`, but -- based on the documentation -- it's not clear to me what I'm missing. So, my questions are: (1) why does the code yield this error, and (2) how can I plot the data using `ggplot`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach would work if you put the `intercept` and `slope` in the aesthetics, e.g.

```
df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = slope, intercept = intercept))
```

If you don't want to use the aesthetics, you need to reference the column of the dataframe:

```
df %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_abline(slope = df$slope, intercept = df$intercept)
```